# convert a bytearray to a 2-dimensional intarray

Tags: c#

can someone help to write a method that converts a byte array to a 2-dimensional int array?!

I have written that:

```
internal int[][] byteToInt(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        int width = (int)Math.Sqrt(byteArray.Length);
        int[][] tmp = new int[width][];
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            tmp[i] = new int[width];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                tmp[i][j]=(int)byteArray[(i*width+j)];
            }
        }
        return tmp;
    }
```

but that is not working properly....

Comment: What are the conditions of putting byte array to 2D int array, after how many bytes ? how to manage row number/col numbers ?

Comment: What is happening, and what you expect that it should happen?

Comment: I use a QRCode decorder which converts a Bitmap File into an int array. But in WPF the Class Bitmap is not known, so i converted my Bitmap into an bytearray and now i want to convert the bytearray into an int array, in order that my program can go on...

Comment: You haven't answered my question. What is happening that appears to be wrong?

Comment: the bitmap hast a width of 180px, but in my method the widt from the bytearray is only 110...

Comment: What exactly is `byteArray`? How did you obtain it? What is the code that converted Bitmap into byte array?

Comment: Byte array `_Buffer` is just contents of a file. This contents is not pure image bytes. If you want to ask how to convert image file into image bytes please ask it in another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I think this will do what you want.

If I understand correctly you want to take an image and convert it into a 2-dimensional array of int RGB values.

```
internal int[,] JpgToInt(String fileName)
{
    Bitmap Bitmap = new Bitmap(fileName);

    int[,] ret = new int[Bitmap.Width,Bitmap.Height];

    for (int i = 0; i < Bitmap.Width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Bitmap.Height; j++)
        {
            ret[i, j] = Bitmap.GetPixel(i, j).ToArgb();
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Although it doesn't answer the main question it does solve the problem and the solution to the question would not have.

In answer to the main question there is no way to arbitrarily take a byte array and make it into a 2-dimensional int array as you have no idea what the dimensions of the 2-dimensional array will be.

The code you are using to get the image from the file is the correct way to get the raw binary of a jpg file but it doesn't get the image it self. (see wikipedia for [how jpeg files are formated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jpeg))

Comment: Hi Alex, yeee that works like a charm...but i can´t use the Bitmap Class cause WPF doesn´t know it...:(

Comment: How are you trying to use it? you will need to have System.Drawing referenced.

Comment: In WPF you don´t have System.Drawing...Thats my Problem!

Comment: You just add it as a reference as I said, in the solution explorer go to your project and it will have a references folder right click that and click add then just find System.Drawing and add it then just put "using System.Drawing;" with your other using statements.

Answer (score 0):

The Code for converting the JPG into a bytearray:

```
public byte[] FileToByteArray(string _FileName)
    {
        byte[] _Buffer = null;

        try
        {
            // Open file for reading
            System.IO.FileStream _FileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(_FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

            // attach filestream to binary reader
            System.IO.BinaryReader _BinaryReader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(_FileStream);

            // get total byte length of the file
            long _TotalBytes = new System.IO.FileInfo(_FileName).Length;

            // read entire file into buffer
            _Buffer = _BinaryReader.ReadBytes((Int32)_TotalBytes);

            // close file reader
            _FileStream.Close();
            _FileStream.Dispose();
            _BinaryReader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception _Exception)
        {
            // Error
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in process: {0}", _Exception.ToString());
        }

        return _Buffer;
    }
```